# List group in a pre with Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a list group in bootstrap that comes in a pre because it contains other data, the problem is that when I put the list group in the pre the items are separated from the list.

Code :

```
<pre>
  Text
  A lot of messy text that needs pre to look good
  <ul class='list-group'>
    <li class='list-group-item active'>lista</li>
    <li class='list-group-item'>test</li>
  </ul>
</pre>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40698/

I found a possible solution:

```
.list-group-item {
    margin-bottom: -35px !important;
}
```

At first glance it works, but I wanted to know if there was any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS, the `<pre>` element's default value is setting `white-space: pre`.

Just change your CSS to something like this:

```
pre {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: The effect that causes pre breaks with that css, I need to use pre so that the text looks good, otherwise it is piled up

Comment: Change the CSS again to: pre ul {white-space: normal;}